# Литература по оконным приложениям

Tags: книги, c++, visual-studio

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, литературу по Visual С++ по созданию оконных приложений с помощью компонентов (Button и т. д.). В Visual C 6.0. они были. В 2010 не могу понять, как вообще визуально строить интерфейс приложения. С++ Builder не предлагать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Visual C++ 2010 для начинающих. Автор: В.Пахомов. Сам пользовался, книга понравилась)

Answer (score 0):

Все есть на MSDN: [Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/60k1461a.aspx).

> Visual C++ 2010 предоставляет мощную и гибкую среду разработки, позволяющую создавать приложения для Microsoft Windows и приложения, основанные на Microsoft .NET.